# history.push to /login (on logout) is not working in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When the users logs in using his/her credentials, the name of the user is displayed on the `Header` component. The user can log out using the `logout` link.

[image]

When the user clicks on the `logout` link, I remove the `loggedInUser` object saved in local storage. Then, I direct the user to the `/login` route, where I show the login form to the user.

When I use `history.push("/login")`, and click on the `logout` link, nothing happens. The `loggedInUser` object does not get removed from the local storage, and I am not directed to the `login` route. However, if I use `window.location = "/login"`, everything works as expected.

Why is `hitory.push("/login")` not working as expected?

**Header.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "./stateSlices/loginSlice";

const Header = ({ history }) => {
  const { loggedInUser } = useSelector((state) => state.login);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const logoutSubmitHandler = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    localStorage.removeItem("loggedInUser");
    window.location = "/login"; // THIS works
    // history.push("/login"); // THIS does not work
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul className="navbar-list">
          {loggedInUser ? (
            <div className="dropdown">
              <button
                className="btn btn-lg btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                type="button"
                id="dropdownMenu2"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                {loggedInUser.firstName}
              </button>
              <div
                className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
                aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2"
              >
                <button
                  className="dropdown-item"
                  type="button"
                  onClick={logoutSubmitHandler}
                >
                  Logout
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <Link to="/login" className="navbar-list-item">
              Register/Login
            </Link>
          )}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Header);
```

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginForm from "./components/LoginForm";
import RegisterForm from "./components/RegisterForm";
import Welcome from "./components/Welcome";
import PasswordResetFormEmail from "./components/PasswordResetFormEmail";
import PasswordResetFormPassword from "./components/PasswordResetFormPassword";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/password/reset/:token"
          component={PasswordResetFormPassword}
        />
        <Route
          path="/account/password/forgot"
          component={PasswordResetFormEmail}
        />
        <Route path="/register" component={RegisterForm} />
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
        <Route path="/welcome" component={Welcome} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: No, I don't have history installed separately.

Comment: https://github.com/sundaray/auth-trial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your redux slice:

```
reducers: {
  logout(state, action) {
    // state.user = null; // <-- Typo error
    state.loggedInUser = null; // This is the correct one
  },
},
```

But, after fixing the typo, I would recommend that you refactor your code and create a "PrivateRoute" component as demoed in the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow):

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const { loggedInUser } = useSelector((state) => state.login);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        loggedInUser ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

and use it in `App` component for all the private routes:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/welcome">
  <Welcome />
</PrivateRoute>
```

Now, this way, `PrivateRoute` will take care of "redirection" to the login page, all you need to do is "clear" the `loggedInUser` in your redux state.

---

Note that it is better to use "children" form when defining Routes. See [What's the better way to configure routes in App.js in React with react-router-dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67087661/2873538)

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();

const logoutSubmitHandler = () => {
  history.push("/login");
}
```

Comment: `history` prop is not available to `Header` because its not rendered using `Route`.

Comment: You don't have to pass history as prop to header. Just import useHistory from react-router-dom in the Header component and then use my code snippet

Comment: What is the problem if I get access to `history` using `withRouter`?

Comment: By the way, I used `useHistory`. It's not working.

Comment: Maybe try import { Router } instead of import { BrowserRouter as Router } . Because BrowserRouter ignores the history prop.